# Wordpress won't load .JS on certain browser. "net::ERR_ABORTED 599"

Tags: javascript, wordpress, opera, mozilla

my Wordpress site has this bizarre error that will only happen in Opera at this moment. (It's happened before in Mozilla but had no other choice but to migrate of browser at the time).

It's happened again after I restored a database backup. Basically Opera at the moment won't load up any .js files making the site not work as intended. The problem will only happen on this specific browser and on this specific website.

Any other Wordpress websites will work fine. Also if I use Google Chrome on the problematic website it will work fine as well.

Ctrl+Shift+J will give me like 40 lines of these:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 599 ()
core.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 599 ()
widget.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 599 ()
```

I've tried clearing website and site's cache, disabled all plugins but no avail. And I really don't want to migrate of browser again because of this. Any help or ideas would be appreciated, can't really find anybody else with this same exact issue.

Could be a server issue? Anything I can do in Cpanel?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 599 is a timeout error. Here's some information about 599: https://www.belugacdn.com/blog/cdn/error-599/

Comment: I see but it's weird that is only happening on a single browser. Not to mention the fixes provided there won't help my case.